# How do you pass tables from C++ to lua using luabind?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I have a C++ function that I want to return a lua table

```
luabind::object getPosition(void)
{
    luabind::table=luabind::newtable(this->state);
    table["x"]=this->position[0];
    table["y"]=this->position[1];
    return table
}
```

The problem is that when lua calls this function, a number is returned instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
luabind::object getPosition(void)
{
    luabind::object result =luabind::newtable(this->state);
    result["x"]=this->position[0];
    result["y"]=this->position[1];
    return result 
}
```